# Should text formatting contribute to the comment character count?

Tags: discussion, comments, formatting

There is a limited character count per comment on Stack Overflow (totally understandable). However, I'm surprised to find that characters used for text formatting contribute to this. For example, if I wish to *italicise* my text, the underscore characters each size contribute to the character count, despite the fact you cold argue you'd never see those characters.

Why is this the case?

No big deal, but I'm curious as to why this decision has been made.

Comment: I think it is not an important thing (the important is that comments should be short, exactly how short, is not important). I think it is useful that you are thinking on it (+1). I think it is dupe (no bad).

Comment: I agree it's not important, was just curious.

Comment: Aha! This why suddenly that old question of mine (which I already had forgotten!) is getting so much activity. Funny thing is, that although the answer should be something like "because it is not enough important to us to implement and maintain" all the 'answers' explain how to either circumvent the character-limitation or say that you shouldn't need that many characters in the first place...

Comment: @dingalapadum PRECISELY the point I was making. I'm not even disputing whether it's of importance, it's not, not really - but the question's still valid and was, up until I mentioned it yesterday, unanswered.

Comment: But the thing which *really* bugs me is: why the heck does your question get more upvotes than mine?!?! It's just not fair! I should probably open a question about upvotes from linked/dupped questions to count towards the original question. I'm sure the mods on Meta would love the idea ;D

Comment: Just to make sure nobody gets offended on SO: I was kidding in my previous comment.